# Laravel 4 Input file return empty after post .. why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Laravel 4 Input file return empty after post .. why?

html code in blade file

```
<div id='images'>
    <input type='hidden' id='imagescounter' name='imagescounter' value='1'>
    <input type='file' id='image_1' name='image_1' class='col-md-12' onchange='$("#task").val("uploadtotemp");$("#temp_count").val(1);$("#addbirdfrm").submit();' >
</div>
<?php
    $image = asset("images/controls/previewbird.png");
?>
<a href='#' onclick='addimageinput($("#imagescounter").val(),"{{ $image }}");return false;' id='addimageinput'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign top-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<div id='previews'>
    <input type='hidden' name='temp_count' id='temp_count' value=''>
    <img id='preview_1' name='preview_1' src='{{ asset("images/controls/previewbird.png") }}'>
</div>
```

and my jquery in the same file

```
<script>
    $("#addbirdfrm").submit(function(e){
        if($('#task').val() == 'uploadtotemp'){
            $('#preview_'+$('#temp_count').val()).attr('src', '{{ asset("images/controls/loading_facebook.gif") }}');
            var dataString = $('#addbirdfrm').serializeArray();
            e.preventDefault();
            var token =  $("input[name=_token]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "{{ URL::route('get-temp') }}",
                data : dataString,
                success : function(data){
                    //$('#date').val(data);
                    alert(data);
                }
            },"json");
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

and in my controller file

```
public function postGetTemp(){
    return Input::file('image_1')->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

Why this code return empty data? and data return 0 when change controller code to

```
public function postGetTemp(){
    return 0;
}
```

so why does `Input::file('image_1')` not return data?

Answer (score 0):

`Input::file()` is a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` object, not a printable element. Use `var_dump()` or `dd()` to read it.

Comment: returned 

array(14) {  ["id"]=>  string(2) "12"  ["gander"]=>  string(4) "male"  ["category_0"]=>  string(1) "0"  ["category_counter"]=>  string(1) "0"  ["full_category"]=>  string(0) ""  ["date"]=>  string(10) "2014-11-28"  ["age"]=>  string(0) ""  ["ringdetails"]=>  string(0) ""  ["nots"]=>  string(0) ""  ["imagescounter"]=>  string(1) "1"  ["temp_count"]=>  string(1) "1"  ["task"]=>  string(12) "uploadtotemp"  ["where"]=>  string(4) "bird"  ["_token"]=>  string(40) "LCx75UalaBqEsTsKMi3HbdofveNP3JlW8uSnkiJr"}

not returned image_1 :(

Comment: What do you need to do with this file? You have to use `Input::file('image_1')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);` to upload it.

Comment: Input::file('image_1')->getClientOriginalName(); return null why?

Comment: Take an eye on http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files to understand the methods you can use on `Input::file()` (there are a few)

Comment: can't get  $fileName from Input::file('image_1') because return null

Comment: Try to check if it gets it with `Input::hasFile('image_1')`

Comment: returned false 

bool(false)

Comment: I found out what's your problem. You can't upload a file using `serializeArray()`. Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/8758614#8758614

Comment: when i used var_dump(Input::all()) returned all input true values but only image_1 input not return value

Comment: Hey @khaledbelal is it possible that maybe you forgot to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `form`?